# Why would a moderator delete comments about nonsense down-votes and not the down-votes themselves?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes, moderation

Yesterday there was this question on SO

**Link:**
[PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377348/pdo-construct-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servic/21377404)

**Situation:**

My Answer was, and is, 100% accurate according to the manual which is also linked in the Answer itself. Anyhow some trigger happy people came over and started a down vote bandwagon and I got -4. Then some people realized no that is correct and I got 2 up-votes. I and the OP had some comments about those down-voters and today those comments are gone. That answer was correct and was accepted after the OP confirmed it.

**Question:**

Although I understand that chatty comments don't do any good and its perfectly fine for a moderator to remove them but my question is that why would a moderator delete those comments and he/she does nothing about those nonsense down-votes themselves? Why the comments about the wrong use of a feature are wrong and the wrong use of that feature itself is not wrong? If those comments had to be removed, shouldn't the incorrect down votes be removed too?

Comment: A moderator cannot remove downvotes, and people are free to vote as they wish.

Comment: Then why are people not free to `comment` as they wish? As long as those are respectful and not negative and within the guidelines?

Comment: Comments serve to clarify a question. If they don't, they can be removed. And even clarifying comments can be removed if they have become obsolete. If you think people are generally misusing features, take it to Meta.

Comment: That's what I did, brought it to Meta.

Comment: Keep going to -100 Down-votes, that helps explain my point.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky to answer your question from comments. Stack Exchange model is not a social networking site where people are free to *chat* and exchange opinions. Stack Overflow is a professional Q&A site and there is no room for discussion about features. If you want to discuss anything about the site don't do it below your answer on SO, do it here on META.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You have 3 upvotes (+30), 4 downvotes (-8), and the accepted answer (+15). By my math you've gotten 37 rep and are listed at the top of the answers. What exactly would be accomplished by having a mod review the validity of your claim here?

Comment: @jmac my down votes are not my issue, those keep coming and going. Ill informed down votes are an issue, that answer is properly formatted as per SO guidelines and is helpful to the OP as well, but why can people down vote and not talk about down votes? Why were those comments removed which simply referred to the fact that those down votes do not make sense. I do not need a mod review and I did not flag for it

Comment: @mehow that makes sense, thanks. But how can a `professional Q&A site`  allow non professional voting on will?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky if you hover over the voting arrows (do both, up and down) you will see what voting is mainly for.

Comment: So Hanky, you are upset that comments (that were flagged) were removed, while downvotes (which were not flagged) were not removed? And how exactly would you expect anyone to be able to judge whether the downvotes are ill-informed or not? I don't understand what it is you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I had a comment there which goes like `Funny I think these down votes are due to a bug`. I wish to know what was In it which would allow it to be flagged and removed? Why can I not be surprised about the down votes and mention it?

Comment: @jmac And what am I trying to accomplish here? Just trying to have a `discussion` as tagged, in order to understand things better. I don't want any mod reviews or up-votes by crying things out. I just wanted to discuss some `why`s and that is it. Is that forbidden?

Comment: Not forbidden, but if you want to have a good discussion, you should be sure to frame the topic of that discussion clearly. What is the issue you are facing with this? What do you think should be done? What don't you understand about the way the current system works? All this reads as is, *"I am angry I got downvotes"* which is probably why your question is getting more downvotes.

Comment: Thanks that makes sene

Answer (score 11):

Comments and down-votes are completely separate. People can comment without downvoting, or downvote without commenting. In your example, no comments were left by the people who downvoted.

Those who do comment are free to remove their comments at any time should they wish to.

Those who vote are free to remove their votes, if the post has been edited at some point after the vote was cast.

Moderators *can* delete comments, if need-be.

Moderators *cannot* delete votes.

In the future, avoid accusing folks who comment of voting a certain way. You're probably wrong, but even if you're right you're just encouraging them to *not bother leaving comments* in the future - I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: "In your example, no comments were left by the people who downvoted." Isn't voting supposed to be anonymous?

Comment: Heh, I probably should've mentioned that all of the comments were left by the answer's author and question's author.